# Accessing ArrayList of Fragment after state restored in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist

I'm trying to update arraylist present inside fragment by parent activity upon some data change. It **works well** during normal cases. But when activity was in background and **system kills it**, then after **state of the activity and fragment restored**, accessing arraylist from activity **returns null**.

I have added check to restore the arraylist inside fragment using `onActivityCreated` method, this does restore the array but, array is null when accessing through parent activity.

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    // initialized during onCreate
    Fragment fragment;
   .
   .
   .
   private void updateFragmentArray(){
   .
   .
   .
     fragment.putArrayItem(myItem);
  }
}
```

Fragment Class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
     // initialized in #onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
     private ArrayList<MyItem> itemArrayList;
     .
     .
     .
     public void putArrayItem(MyItem myItem) {

     // THIS LINE THROWS NULL POINTER EXCEPTION 
     // FOR ARRAYLIST
     this.itemArrayList.add(myItem);

     }
     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            this.itemArrayList= (ArrayList<MyItem>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(GRID_ITEMS);
        }
        else {
            this.itemArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        }
        adapter = new RewardsGridFragmentRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), this.itemArrayList);
        recyclerViewGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Any Solution? What I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: How'd you create an `itemArrayList`? Looks like it's not recreated during activity restart.

Comment: it does in onActivityCreated(),I first check if I have value from saved instance, if not I simply initialize it to new ArrayList

Comment: see updated question

Comment: Is there any possibility, that `putArrayItem` executes before `onActivityCreated`? I can't see any suspicious in provided code, you should analyse the rest of code.

Answer (score -4):

Try to use lifecycle methods:

> OnPause()

`OnPause()` is called when the user receives an event like a call or a text message when `onPause()` is called the Activity may be partially or completely hidden.

You would want to save user data in `onPause()`, in case he hits back button without saving the data explicitly.

> OnResume()

`OnResume()` is called when the user resumes his Activity which he left a while ago, say he presses home button and then comes back to app, `onResume()` is called.

You can do the network related updates here or anything of this sort in `onResume()`.

> onStop()

`onStop()` Method In Android Activity Life Cycle When Activity is in background then `onPause()` method will execute. 
After a millisecond of that method next `onStop()` method will execute. 
Means here also Activity is not visible to user when `onStop()` executed. 
We will use `onStop()` method to stop Api calls etc. This `onStop()` method will clean up all your activities resources.